# Getting NAN on safari when using a javascript date

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am working on something, in which I am required to subtract 2 dates from one another, the difference would then be multiplied by the price per night of the event.

The issue I am  having is that, while this works perfectly when using Chrome or Firefox, I am getting "NAN if I am using safari.

Date to and from are obtained using the php code below:

```
<?php 
// displays days with leading 0s
$options = array();

for ($i=1; $i<32; $i++) {
$theday = date('d', mktime(0,0,0,0,$i,2000));
$sel = ($i == date('d') ? 'selected="selected"' : '');
$options[] = "<option value= \"{$theday}\" {$sel}>{$theday}
</option>";
}

$options_list = join("\r\n", $options);
echo "<div class='select' id='date'><select class=\"short-input day-to\" name=\"day_to\">{$options_list}</select></div>";
?>

<?php
$options = array();

for ($i = 1; $i<13; $i++) {
    $themonth = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$i,2, 2000));
    $month = date('m', mktime(0,0,0,$i,2,2000));
    $sel =($i == date('n') ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
    $options[] = "<option value=\"{$month}\" {$sel}>{$themonth}
    </option>";
}
$options_list = join("\r\n", $options);
echo "<div class='select' id='month'><select class=\"short-input month-to\" name=\"month_to\" size=\"1\">{$options_list}</select></div>";
?>

<?php 
/* build selection list for the year */
$today = time(); // stores today's date
$startYr = date("Y", $today); // get the year from $today
echo "<div class='select' id='year'>
                                <select class=\"short-input year-to\" name='year_to'>\n";
for ($year=$startYr;$year<=$startYr+10;$year++)
{
    echo " <option value= $year";
    if ($startYr == $year)
    {
        echo "";
    }
    echo " > $year</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n</div>\n";
?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ju097j4z/#

Are there any solutions to this.

Comment: parseInt all your numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `Date.parse(monthFrom + ' ' + dayFrom + ' ' + yearFrom);` in your fiddle use `new Date(yearFrom, monthFrom, dayFrom);`  *note that in js month starts with 0

Comment: Yes, it is standard Date constructor in js [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)